# Image / Video capture issue with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` (Xcode - Version 6.2 (6C131e), iOS SDK 8.0 and above) to capture videos and photos in my iPad application. The media capture part works fine. But I'm facing three strange issues. I get these issues with and without auto layout and also allowing all orientations and only landscape.

1. While video recording is going on or after capturing a photo, if I press the **Home** button and come back to the app again, the picker interface goes back to the way it is before capturing any media. That is, it shows the begin capture button, toggle camera button and cancel button. Only the cancel button works. Apart from that the whole interface looks frozen. I can try capturing again only if I press cancel and bring up the picker again.
2. Whenever I try to present the image picker, this warning pops up

   ```
   Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
   ```
3. Whenever I try to bring up the picker for capturing video only, I get the following message in the console

   ```
   Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
   (
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14de8a00 V:|-(10.5)-[CAMFlipButton:0x14defa40]   (Names: '|':CAMBottomBar:0x14eed5a0 )>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14de56d0 CAMShutterButton:0x14ef1440.centerY == CAMBottomBar:0x14eed5a0.centerY>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dcfdb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[PLImagePickerCameraView:0x153da800(0)]>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dcc570 CAMBottomBar:0x14eed5a0.height == PLImagePickerCameraView:0x153da800.height>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14efbc50 V:[CAMFlipButton:0x14defa40]-(0)-[UIView:0x14ee64d0]>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14efbc80 UIView:0x14ee64d0.bottom == CAMShutterButton:0x14ef1440.top>"
   )

   Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
   ```

   ```
   Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
   ```

All these do not affect the capture process in any way. But 1 has negative effect as far as user experience goes

I have searched and found questions related to 2 and 3 asked on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions worked for me

Im using the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    imagePickerController            = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    switch (mediaType)
    {
        case 0:
            [imagePickerController setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            NSArray *mediaTypeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
            [imagePickerController setMediaTypes:mediaTypeArray];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    imagePickerController.delegate   = self;
}

[self presentViewController:imagePickerController  animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope someone out there has faced similar problems as this is a pretty basic operation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be on Apple’s side and there isn’t anything we can do. Fortunately, besides being annoying in the debugger, it doesn’t cause user related issues.